# How to send the JSON Object data to mysql Data Base using Jquery+Hibernate +Maven on Restfull web services?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, hibernate, maven

I am sending JSON object data over AJAX to Spring+Hibernate based application. When I am using advanced chrome browser I am able to send but through JQuery Not able to send. I am using hard coded JSON data.

{       "custName": "Navin1",
            "custMobile": "876532468",
            "custEmail": "abc@gmal.com",
            "custAddress": "BAnaore"
}

I am getting the following message in firefox console.
**Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at localhost:8080. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
        var custName = $('#custName').val();
        var custMobile = $('#custMobile').value;
        var custEmail = $('#custEmail').value;
        var custAddress = $('#custAddress').value;  

        var jsonData=JSON.stringify({
            "custName": "Navin1",
            "custMobile": "876532468",
            "custEmail": "abc@gmal.com",
            "custAddress": "BAnaore"
        });
        $.ajax({
                 url: "http://localhost:8080/HomeServiceProvider/customer/saveCustomer",
                 type: "POST",
                 dataType: "json",                  
                 data: jsonData,
                 contentType: "application/json",
             success: function(response){
                alert(JSON.stringify(response));
             },
             error: function(err){
                alert(JSON.stringify(err));
             }
        });

      });
    });
</script>
</head>
    <body>  
        <form>
            <fieldset style="text-align:right; width:300px">
                <legend><b>Registration Form</b></legend>
                Name <input type="text" id="custName" name="custName"/><br/>
                Mobile No <input type="text" id="custMobile" name="custMobile"/><br/>
                Email <input type="text" id="custEmail" name="custEmail"/><br/>
                Address <input type="text" id="custAddress" name="custAddress"/><br/>

                <button>Save Data</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>                 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your question? Did you do a web search to understand what that error means?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is in the error message.

"This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS."

Looks like you loaded the page from loaclhost:8080 but are making a request to 192.168.1.12:8080 The domain of the request needs to match the domain of the page.

Comment: thanks for replay but I just removed it when I pasting in stack-over flow.